# Committed Vs Retired instruction

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, instructions

It may be a stupid question but I'm not able to find a clear explanation about these 2 phases of an instruction life. My initial thinking was that they are synonymous but I'm not sure anymore. I start to think that

1. For a load commit and retire happens at the same time
2. For a store the commit happen when the instruction update the registers and the retire happens when the store actually leave the store buffer.

Is this wrong ? Does anyone have 2 clears definitions of those terms ?

Cheers.

Comment: Stores get committed when they leave the SB (they are committed to L1 or memory). Stores are retired when their uOPs are removed from the ROB after they are executed (address and data put in the SB). These two events are unrelated since stores are a fire-and-forget type of operation. I wouldn't use "Committed" for loads. Retirement for loads is similar but they complete execution only after receiving the data.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for the clarification, just to understand. Once the store is fired by the STB  it is written in memory correct ? Isn't it a problem in case the speculation was wrong ? My idea of "retirement" ( probably wrong) is that only when the instruction is retired it's possible to write in the L2/memory. No ?

Comment: @haster8558 Good point. I believe stores can commit only after they have retired.

Comment: @haster8558: Store data enters the store buffer when the store-data uop executes.  The buffer prevents it from committing to L1d until *after* the store uop is known to be non-speculative (retired from the ROB).  At that point it has definitely happened, and can't be rolled back.  Even if an interrupt or exception happens, it will still be committed and become globally visible.  (So a large store buffer is potentially bad for IRQ latency with lots of cache-miss stores in flight, because x86's strong memory model requires stores to commit in program order, and so would a serializing insn.)

Comment: Note that I'm talking about committing *the store itself* (making it globally visible), vs. committing the store instruction to the retirement state of the ROB, making it non-speculative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These terms have no standard definitions. I have seen them being used to mean different things in different books or processor designs:

- In Intel processors, retirement occurs when the reorder buffer entries occupied by the instruction get deallcoated. Memory stores have one additional stage called commit in which the store is actually performed. That's because Intel processors have store buffers where stores can be marked as retired.<sup>1</sup>
- Hennessy and Patterson's book mostly uses the term "commit" in the chapter on out-of-order execution. Even stores get performed in the commit stage. Sometimes it uses the term "retire" but without giving a definition that would distinguish it from commit. However, in Appendix C, stores are performed in the 4th stage, called the memory stage, while register updates are performed in the 5th stage, which is called writeback.
- Some books use the terms "complete" and "commit" where "complete" means "retire" in Intel processors and "commit" means "commit". By the way, Intel also uses the term "complete" in their manual which may mean something other than retire depending on the context.
- Sometimes the term "commit" refers to updating both the register and memory state while the term "retire" refers to deallocating architectural resources.
- Sometimes there are used interchangeably. For example, there are academic proposals for microarchitectures that can dispatch stores out-of-order but without using any store buffers. Stores are performed on retirement from the ROB itself.

The terms might be used to mean other things in other contexts. Generally, you can deduce what they mean from the way they are being used by the author and from the overall context.

---

Footnote 1:  Intel has [a patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20090144500A1/en) on an alternate implementation that allows stores to leave the store buffer out-of-order, which they don't implement it in any of their CPUs.

It would be possible to commit stores out-of-order before retirement if the L1D is equipped with a mechanism to distinguish between the globally visible state and the locally visible state of each valid cache line in the cache. This mechanism would be needed to maintain the visible order of the stores. In this hypothetical design, it's also possible to commit stores speculatively, which would require flushing (some of or all the) locally visible states on mispredictions. A store buffer entry that holds a store could optionally be freed when the store commits even if it did not retire yet.

Comment: Intel often says "complete locally" to talk about retirement from the ROB, including a store retiring from the ROB, but not necessarily committing from the memory-order buffer to L1d cache yet.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LFENCE.html

Comment: Your edit that added the idea of tagging L1d to mark lines that aren't coherent (yet) is an unusual idea.  I guess it is theoretically possible, but I would have thought it would add more complexity in more places than a larger store buffer.  And mis-speculation for stores then results in wrong evictions, and more RFOs.  I moved it to a footnote to avoid any implication that any real CPUs work that way.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree it's unusual. I also don't know if any Intel processors use it. Note that Intel itself has a [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20090144500A1/en) on this very idea. While they describe the technical details there, it's not clear to me to what extent this helps performance and what is the trade-off compared to increasing the store buffer size instead. They basically only say "...to improve store performance in a microprocessor by allowing out-of-order issuance of read-for-ownership operations and more efficiently using the store buffer latency periods."

Comment: Oh right, I was forgetting it would allow stores to leave the MOB out of  order, that could be a significant advantage.